# Why does a Joomla component not work when SEF urls are turned on?

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, sef

I have just installed the [Joomla Jukebox component](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/multimedia/audio-players-a-gallery/9117) last night. The player does not work when I turn on SEF URL within Joomla (I have version 1.5.x). That is, when I press play on the player (its a swf) the song does not play, but the song plays once I switch back to non-SEF'ed URLs.

Have anyone experienced this issue or a similar problem with any other components that they have worked with?

Would anyone know why ? and possibly suggest how I can quickly patch it myself?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the code of your component does not use the Joomla router to create URLs. Why don't you ask the developers of that component? Probably you are not the first to run into this issue..